# Android studio multiple project style issue

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android project using another one as library. So far I've been working on Eclipse with Maven, now I want to migrate to Android Studio and Gradle.
The problem is that I use to do the following in Eclipse:

Library project:

```
<style name="some_theme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

And then in my main project:

```
<style name="some_theme">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

So, if the theme name is the same in Eclipse I get whats been defined in both themes, but in Android studio I only get what's on the main project

Has someone encounter this type of issue before? Does someone know a way to solve it? (Other than just copy all what's on the library project...)

Regards

Jose

Answer (score -1):

That shouldn't work. When you define two styles with the same name in two different places, you should run into a naming conflict. There is no documented style resource merging feature. The fact that it works in Eclipse with ADT is probably accidental.

The correct way to do this is to define one style in your library, and inherit from that style in your application.

For example, in your library project:

```
<style name="SomeThemeBase">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

Then in your application project:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="SomeThemeBase">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

This way you do not create a naming conflict, but your app's theme still inherits the properties you defined on the base theme.

Comment: In Eclipse/Maven it's merging styles beautifully, seems strange that it would happen by accident. One would think that's a missing feature in Android Studio/Gradle or maybe some configuration that I'm missing. 
I haven't been able to find some "official" documentation about this.

Comment: The fact that it is an undocumented "feature" is what tells me it is a bug. If it were a true feature, there would need to be documentation on which styles take precendence and such.

Comment: I actually use this library project in more than one project, other thing that I do is to add different parent="..."  on the same style in every project. since themes don't support multiple inheritance I just can't use your solution...

Comment: You are free to [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/) or post to the [tools Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adt-dev) if you feel like this behavior is incorrect.